# For iOS Mobile web automation,is a provisioning profile required?

Tags: ios, xcode, mobile, automation, appium

I am trying to automate a web application using iOS mobile web Safari.
And I am facing the Xcode build 65 failed error. The solutions for this says that I need a provisioning profile. But I do not have a developers team membership yet in my apple account. Do I need that for mobile web as well?

Answer (score 0):

If you are automating on real iPhone then you will need provisioning profile. Try using simulator as you won't need provisioning profile there.

Comment: Thank you Shreyansh for the response.However I have to continue with real device only as per instructions.Hence I should have a provisioning profile. I have seen that only if we buy a developers program,I will get a profile and signing certificate. Is there a way to get a profile/certificate for free? If yes ,kindly update me.Otherwise I will go ahead and purchase the developers program.